# How to compare binary fields longer than 64 bits

Tags: sql, t-sql, bit-manipulation, xor

I have a new database bound application. I have a TableA with Column1 as binary(128) that always contains only 1 flag raised. I have another TableB that contains Column5 binary(128) that contains bitmasks that when applied to TableA.Column1 produces all records that have at least one flag raised.
Example

```
TableA
Column1   Record
0000      Product1
0001      Product2
0010      Product3
0100      Product4
1000      Product5

TableB
Column5       Column6
0110          'Cool products'
0101          'Fun products'
```

When applied

```
declare @mask as int
select @mask = CAST(TableB.Column5 as int) from TableB WHERE TableB.Column6 = 'Cool products'

select *
from TableA as t
WHERE t.Column1 & @mask <> 0
```

procuces Product3 and Product4. Everything works as intended. I chose binary for simplicity of flag assignment and fanstastic performance and flexibility of customizing search masks.
The problem is that bigint is 64 bit long and I need to apply masks to 128 bit long column so how do I chieve that same functionality as presented above?

Comment: You mean 128 products is enough for everybody?

Comment: The SQL way to model this would be to model these relationships as table data, in appropriate columns. Are you so sure that you need to destroy conventional querying capabilities all in the name of "performance"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - no, 128 products is not enough. This is actually a property of raw material used in production. But one property can be changed into another in production process thus mask is needed to group them. As specifications change, so will the material properties included thus the search masks

Comment: Also, `^` is exclusive-or, so it's not doing what you though it was - your shown query will always retrieve all rows as long as your Table B bitmasks contain more than one set bit and Table A bitmasks only contain one set bit. Not quite sure what to make of `Product 1` since it doesn't have any bits set.

Comment: What about having two `BIGINT` columns with only one bit set in one of the columns?

Comment: @Dommer - how would you achieve that?

Comment: In `TableA` you have `Column1` which is a `BIGINT` and can have 64 flags set. Add `Column1A` with another `BIGINT` so you can have another 64 flags. Then `TableB` would also need two columns in the same way (`Column5` and `Column5A`). Then you could compare `TableA.Column1` with `TableB.Column5` and `TableA.Column1A` with `TableB.Column5A`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, I meant &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
create table #a
(
X varbinary(24) null
)
create table #k
(
K varbinary(24) null
)

select X,K
abs(substring(X,1,8)&cast(substring(K,1,8) as bigint))
+abs(substring(X,9,8)&cast(substring(K,9,8) as bigint))
+abs(substring(X,17,8)&cast(substring(K,17,8) as bigint)) as result
 from #a,#K
```

but I discourage to do such sort of manipulations to organize your taxonomy. I think it would be much better to use relations and common SQL technique.
I haven't seen any case in real life, when such technique results into performance gain.